# Can mobile websites (not apps) access androids GPS Radio

Tags: gps

We're creating a brief for a mobile website (not web app) and would like to know if a mobile website can access a handset's built in GPS radio to display the handset's location on a map.

In short is GPS functionality limited to apps alone?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While Websites can not directly access the GPS, then can get the current location from the device (But of course **only** if the user has granted the permission). I think that this is done via HTML5's gelocation API, but I am not sure.